# How to encode special characters for LDAP query in cURL

Tags: curl, ldap, urlencode

Let's say I want to run a query like:

```
ldaps://ldap.company.com/CN=Richards\, Renée,OU=Blah,DC=company,DC=com?field1,field2,field3?sub?(&(objectClass=user))
```

I found that I had to percent-encode the `é` using Windows-1252 encoding table ( `%e9` rather than `%C3%A9`). Otherwise, I would get "No such object".

But now I need to query a DN that has a special character that doesn't exist in Windows-1252.

```
ldaps://ldap.company.com/CN=Richards\, Jūra,OU=Blah,DC=company,DC=com?field1,field2,field3?sub?(&(objectClass=user))
```

How do I encode the `ū`?

Comment: ADVISE: You should rename the entry to use only url safe characters. These type of issues will continue to cause problems with other applications.

Comment: Agreed but I am smaller than the smallest cog in a huge organization. The directory is too big to get all the users even when broken down by OU, so I need to traverse the reporting hierarchy to make sure I get everyone.

Comment: LDAPv3 added Internationalization through the use of Unicode (UTF-8) (All modern servers are v3) so the encoding should be performed using Unicode and not Windows-1252

Comment: Tried that (see original question). Strangely it has no problem returning unicode characters in attributes but will not accept unicode encodings in the request. I was hoping it was something on my end and some flag needs to be set in cURL...

Answer (score 0):

The encodings may be dependent on the LDAP SDK used.

Here is what worked for me:

- CN=Richards, Renée - CN=Richards,%20Ren%C3%A9e
- CN=Richards, Jūra - CN=Richards,%20J%C5%ABra

Comment: Does "LDAP SDK" refer to server side or client side? I'm using cURL 7.62.0

Comment: Client side SDK as many SDKs implement some sort of encoding.